# Is there any Solution for error: condarc invalid yaml and ConfigurationLoadError: Unable to load configuration file?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, navigator

while installing anaconda suite, on running i faced these errors. the first one was `ConfigurationLoadError: Unable to load the configuration file.` and the second was `error: condarc invalid yaml`
Additional: Conda command is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

I highly disagree with Musadiq: deleting .condarc doesn't solve your problem!

The error message indicates a **faulty formatting of .condarc**

1. search for **.condarc**. Here are the **paths** that conda uses itself: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#searching-for-condarc
2. Use an arbitrary **YAML formatter** to solve the issue, e.g.: https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-formatter

Comment: Also when you start it again. it will create a new file and it will work finely.

and I have not mentioned that my solution is 100% true and all other solutions are 200% wong.it is a way.

Comment: The point is, that if you already set various settings in condarc earlier, you will loose them when deleting .condarc. That is why I disagree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `C:\Users\User_name` and search for the file `.condarc`. delete it from this location.
and then restart the anaconda navigator.

Comment: Or maybe you could check the file and try to fix it, instead of just deleting it? To be clear, you haven’t actually solved the problem.

Comment: This was just a possible clue from my side. i am waiting for legends to solve it.

Comment: Also when you start it again. it will create a new file and it will work finely.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Linux. Let me know if this is not the case.

Deleting the .condarc can work as a temporary work around because it is a set of initial configs that run on start up of the Anaconda environment similarly to a .bashrc on the start of the system. That file can be automatically regenerated when deleted and the Anaconda environment is run again to its default values.

However, you MAY want to actually configure settings in the .condarc file and not leave them in their default state (such as if you want the conda environment to default to a miniconda environment you set up). In this case, I have a feeling you are likely working on a tcshrc environment by default. You can check by typing ps $$ (see the command column).

If you are in fact running tcshrc, try running bash to switch envs. Then load your conda environment again (run the activate.csh script) and try your python code again.

As a bonus, it's helpful to understand the difference between these shell environments. I've found a number of different scripts to use or the other and there can be some significant syntax differences. I really like this Quora article's explanation:

[https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-bash-zsh-tcsh-sh-etc-Which-one-should-I-use#:~:text=The%20main%20differences%20between%20them,shell%20geeks%20and%20power%20users](https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-bash-zsh-tcsh-sh-etc-Which-one-should-I-use#:%7E:text=The%20main%20differences%20between%20them,shell%20geeks%20and%20power%20users).

Comment: Sorry for necropost. I use Winodws 10.Any suggestions? My C:\Users\User_name\condarc is empty. Any suggestions/refs, please?

Comment: @MSIS see my answer - conda lists all search paths for .condarc in its documentation

Answer (score 0):

First delete  .condarc.  this file and update conda by using this command

```
conda update conda


conda update anaconda
```

Answer (score -1):

Just search for “.condarc” on your computer.

The .condarc file is frequently found in:

macOS: /Users/Username
Linux: ~/.condarc
Windows: C:\Users\Username

Delete the file and restart your Navigator. Worked for me

Answer (score -1):

If you're using windows, search for ".condarc" in ".../users/username" and delete all its files.

Restart your navigator and it should be up and running immediately.